# Styling from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to style a WPF data-grid from my code behind, as the data-grid is created in code behind.

I have a resource dictionary in my application with all styles.

In XAML I would apply the style to the data-grid as follows:

```
Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
```

How can I achieve this for a data-grid created in code behind as follows:

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dg.Style = this.Resources["DataGridStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the response although this does not seem to work for me. The style is null. I should clarify that the style is in a resource dictionary in another project, it can be used in XAML but I don't think it would be accessible when using 'this'. Any suggestions? UPDATE: Instead of 'this.Resources' I used 'Application.Current.Resources'.